# Wrongly removed my extension in google chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I wrongly removed my extension from developer dashboard, bacause I want to cancel my current submission (to review) and upload another version of chrome store.
After I clicked 'unpublish', my extension is no longer visible in store and I can't see 'cancel and edit' button.
How should I do that? Is that able to publish my updated version of this extension again? Or is that impossible to do that?

Comment: and status is "pending review". but I  can't cancel submission.

Comment: How about you just re-upload a new one, since it was deleted?